# How do I use Instagram to post to my business page but not my personal page?

Tags: facebook, social-media, instagram

I tried asking this question on the Facebook forums but got no answer, maybe someone here might be able to help me with this.

I have a Facebook account and within that same account is my Facebook page for my business. Problem is every time that I try to use Instagram to upload a photo it gets uploaded to my personal/primary Facebook page and not the business page which is under the same email address and password. Instagram ask for this email address and password but how can I just have Instagram upload it to my business page and not my personal page? Or at very least how can I do both?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to manage the applications from within your Instagram account. You need to login and go here: `instagram.com/accounts/manage_access`.

From there, you need to revoke permission from Facebook which is most likely tied to your personal account and why it is posting as such.

Now, login to Facebook and make sure you are using Facebook as your Business page and not your personal account. Go back to `instagram.com/accounts/manage_access` and grant access to Facebook as your business page.

Good luck!

Comment: it says that im not connected to any applications, whats going on?

Comment: manage_access is to manage which external applications can use your API key to post to your instagram. It will not show linked facebook accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook pages have to be managed by Facebook accounts. You can't have an e-mail address that manages a Facebook page without making a Facebook account first, so that suggestion just doesn't work.

The way to do this is first link a Facebook account that is an admin on your Facebook page to instagram. (By default instagram will share to that Facebook account; choose public so everyone can see the pictures you post.) After you've linked, the instagram app on your phone/tablet will let you change to post to any Facebook pages you manage with the account you linked.

Here's the official documentation: https://help.instagram.com/493008720719279/

Answer (score 1):

This might sound strange, but I believe I know what the issue is here.

Your Facebook page should of been made by a private email, that wasn't connected to your primary Facebook. Which is possible. If that would of happened, then I do believe that you could use Instagram with the page. The email would of been treated like a Facebook account for the page.

Your primary Facebook has created the page, so the page is treated differently than as a separate account. It is tied to your primary account now.

The way which I use Instagram pictures with a Facebook Page is to copy them from your phone or device from your personal Facebook and upload them as a picture unto the page itself? Yes, it may be more work, but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem… Every time I tried to unlink my Facebook page through Instagram (profile page - setting - share settings - Facebook - unlink), it wouldn't work. I had to login to Facebook and delete the Instagram app I had loaded on Facebook.

Once this was done, I went back into Instagram and went to -  profile page - setting - share settings - Facebook. Once I logged in, then my business page showed up.

Now I am posting straight to my business page.